# Swap rows/indexes within a JavaScript array using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have a custom directive that is holding an array of JavaScript objects.

The object is a little complex and lengthy but I will display something similar to point out my problem:

A `JSON.stringify` of this displays the following:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "John Doe",
    "EMail": "john@doe.com"
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Jim Doe",
    "EMail": "jim@doe.com"
  },
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "Name": "Jeff Doe",
    "EMail": "jeff@doe.com"
  }
]
```

I am further using `ng-repeat` to display the values in a tabular form on my HTML.

The values are coming from an API call that fetches them from a database.

I want to swap - say the entire Object with Id 1 with the entire Object with Id 3  so that during my tabular display I can see Id 3 object details first and Id 1 object details last, without breaking any functionality.

What would be the best possible solution to do this within the frontend itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just swapping them using a temp variable?

```
var arr = [{"Id":1,"Name":"John Doe","EMail":"john@doe.com"},
 {"Id":2,"Name":"Jim Doe","EMail":"jim@doe.com"},
 {"Id":3,"Name":"Jeff Doe","EMail":"jeff@doe.com"}]
 var tmpObj = arr[0];
 arr[0] = arr[2];
 arr[2] = tmpObj;
```

Comment: I'm running a for loop since the number of objects is large, what would be the best way to switch it within the loop?

Comment: just save indexes of elements you need to swap within the loop (by checking ids or names or whatever you need), and then swap them after the loop as I showed above

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3mL70v4q/2/   This is what I tried, it doesn't seem to be swapping anything though, what am I missing ?

Comment: you need to save indexes, not the elements, see updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/3mL70v4q/3/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reverse the array, use [Array.prototype.reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myController", function($scope) {
  var arr = [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": "John Doe",
      "EMail": "john@doe.com"
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "Name": "Jim Doe",
      "EMail": "jim@doe.com"
    },
    {
      "Id": 3,
      "Name": "Jeff Doe",
      "EMail": "jeff@doe.com"
    }
  ];
  
  $scope.array = arr.reverse();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <div ng-repeat="item in array">
      {{item.Id}} - {{item.Name}} - {{item.EMail}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope it isn't reversing - it's more like swapping them based on indexes